# Why can't I mine my ore in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Okay so I recently lost my palladium drill and I had to make a gold pickaxe so I could mine, unfortunately the pickaxe does not work on any ore (I can't tell if the ore I tried mining with it was palladium or copper, it won't even mine crimson rock). I can mine dirt and rock just not ore. What is wrong here? Please help. To add on, I also tried mining with a lead pickaxe and still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

The [Gold Pickaxe](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Pickaxe) can not mine [Palladium Ore](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Palladium_Ore), since this is a [Hardmode Ore](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Hardmode_Ores). But the Gold Pickaxe should be able to mine [Crimtane Ore](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Crimtane_Ore).

If you are not able to mine any ore at all, your save file may be corrupt, and I suggest you create a new world, and try to do the same thing. If the same phenomenon reoccurs, you should try to re-install the game completely, as this is something that should not happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: Never mind about me not being able to mine any ore. It was palladium I tried to mine before because I just used my lead pickaxe on tin and it worked fine. Any suggestions on what I can use to mine my hardmode ore?

Comment: @cat_ccl [Here are all pickaxes in the game](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Pickaxe), and if you want to mine Palladium Ore, you should choose [Molten Pickaxe](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Molten_Pickaxe) or better.