# I can't mine orichalcum ore with a cobalt pickaxe

Tags: terraria

For some reason, I can't mine orichalcum with a cobalt pickaxe.

It's obviously orichalcum due to its magenta/pink color, and I just made a cobalt pickaxe, so what could be happening?

Answer (score 6):

Its probably [Adamantite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Adamantite_Ore), they look almost the same:

[image: orichalcum vs adamantite]

To mine it you need an Mythril/Orichalcum Drill, Mythril/Orichalcum Pickaxe.

Answer (score 0):

As [Havatra](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/86619/havatra) said in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192056/why-cant-i-mine-my-ore-in-terraria?rq=1) question:

> If you are not able to mine any ore at all, your save file may be
>   corrupt, and I suggest you create a new world and try to do the same
>   thing. If the same phenomenon reoccurs, you should try to re-install
>   the game completely, as this is something that should not happen under
>   normal circumstances.

You should test out if you can mine any other ore, to see if this is the case. If it is really Orichalcum, then this may be your problem.